# How to access container in pod by giving different containerPort number

Tags: kubernetes

I create containers in pod with 8888 and 7777 port.
I am using minikube with --driver=docker.
It create 1/2 running status.
I get respose of nginx with 80 port.

But my expectation is that, it should get respose of nginx when giving ip-pod:7777  and response of httpd when giving ip-pod:8888.
what is issue, can anyone tell me?

Thank you in advance for answer.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod3
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  containers:
    - name: c02
      image: "httpd"
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8888
          name: httpd
    - name: c01
      image: "nginx"
      ports:
        - containerPort: 7777
          name: nginx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, you should seperate your containers in different pods. You can define your pods like below and access them with service in kubernetes:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: httpd
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: httpd
spec:
  containers:
    - name: c02
      image: httpd
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: httpd
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  containers:
    - name: c01
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: httpd-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: httpd
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Hope it helps!